# What does "a whole coke bottle" here mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw that from [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wat):

> 1: I accidentially a whole coke bottle
>   2: You accidentially what?
>   1: A whole coke bottle
>   2: wat

I think "a while coke bottle" here means a whole bottle of coca-cola, but it doesn't make sense.

So what does "a whole coke bottle" really means here?

Comment: That's why it's used as an example of "something that makes absolutely no sense" over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A whole coke bottle" is most likely referring to "a whole bottle of Coca-Cola" as you say, but the sentence doesn't make sense for a different reason.  It's missing something, like the word "spilled", as in:

> I accidentally *spilled* a whole coke bottle.

The purpose of that Urban Dictionary entry is to explain the slang term "wat," and the definition given is "the only proper response to something that makes absolutely no sense."

The sentence was intentionally written to *not* make sense.

The person speaking doesn't say what they accidentally did with/to the whole coke bottle, setting up the example use of the word "wat" as someone else's response.

Thanks to LawrenceC for providing a link to the specific phrase ["I accidentally a whole coke bottle"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally) (and it's usage as part of a larger scope of "I accidentally" phrases used on the internet that lack a verb).

Comment: The "I accidentally [X]" with the missing verb originates from a mistyped post on 4Chan.  http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally

Comment: @LawrenceC Thanks for the link- I the answer to include it